# Entropy of pure split caculated to NaN

Tags: matlab, decision-tree, entropy

I have written a function to calculate entropy of a vector where each element represents number of elements of a class.

```
function x = Entropy(a)
    t = sum(a);
    t = repmat(t, [1, size(a, 2)]);
    x = sum(-a./t .* log2(a./t));
end
```

e.g: `a = [4 0]`, then `entropy = -(0/4)*log2(0/4) - (4/4)*log2(4/4)`

But for above function, the entropy is `NaN` when the split is pure because of `log2(0)`, as in above example. The entropy of pure split should be zero.

How should I solve the problem with least effect on performance as data is very large? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create your own `log2` function

```
function res=mylog2(a)
   res=log2(a);
   res(isinf(res))=0;
end
```

This function, while breaking the `log2` behaviour, can be used in your specific example because you are multiplying the result with the inside of the log, thus making it zero. It is not "mathematically correct", but I believe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but i had to edit it to 'res(isinf(res)) = 0' because log2(0) = -inf.

Comment: @Newbie indeed,  my mistake