# Calculate log using Python but returns "nan"

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am new to Python and currently trying to calculate entropy by using the below codes:

```
def entropy (df, features, response):


    for i in df[features].unique():
        for n in df[response].unique():
#entropy formula: Ht(A)=x*(-x1*log2*x1-x2*log2*x2)
            x=float(len(df[df[features]==i]))/float(len(df))
            x1=float(len(df[(df[features]==i)&(df[response]==n)]))/float(len(df[df[features]==i]))
            x2=1-x1
            HtA=x*(-x1*np.log2(x1)-x2*np.log2(x2))
            return HtA

entropy(dfa, 'LANG', 'HIRE')
```

but it returns "nan" instead of a number, not sure what's wrong with my codes. here's the dataframe i am working with:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98z3z.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just to clarify, features are all columns except the HIRE column, and response is HIRE column, I am trying to calculate entropy for a decision tree model. Thanks!

Comment: The return statement is inside a loop, that means that it will return the result for only the first iteration, I assume this is not intentional?

Comment: Also, have you checked that `x`, `x1` and `x2` are all non `NaN` values before calculating `HtA`?

Comment: I believe this could help you with you "NaN" case: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534797/entropy-of-pure-split-caculated-to-nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534797/entropy-of-pure-split-caculated-to-nan)

Comment: Guys, thank you for all your help! So I moved the return statement outside of the inside loop and added two if conditions to check if log2(0) exists, now the codes are able to calculate the entropy.